# Nokia Maps TypeSelector events

Tags: javascript, jquery, here-api

I added a type selector (nokia.maps.map.component.TypeSelector) to my [nokia map](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/HERE_Maps_API_-_Map_UI_components), but
I need to attach to an event that gets fired as soon as the user changes the map
type, but nokia doesn't seem to list any events for [this object](http://api.maps.nokia.com/2.2.3/apireference/symbols/nokia.maps.map.component.TypeSelector.html)?

I created a little horrible (less than ideal) workaround (seen below)

```
$('.nm_dropDownMenu dd').on('click', function () {
    switch ($(this).prop('class')) {
        case "nm_satellite":
        // do something
        break;
        case "nm_terrain":
        // do something
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TypeSelector` itself doesn't have any events, since it is the `Display` that is changing.
Just add an observer to the `baseMapType` property as shown:

```
map.components.add(new nokia.maps.map.component.TypeSelector());

map.addObserver("baseMapType", 
    function (obj, key, newValue, oldValue) { 
      alert(newValue.label);
    }
);
```

By the way, the **2.2.3** documentation is a couple of years out of date - the **latest** version of the documentation can be found on the [developer.here.com](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/maps) website.